# How to add dyamic assets in PKG

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, yarnpkg, pkg-config, pkgbuild

I'm trying to package an application which essentially takes a screenshot webpages using puppeteer which then stores it in a folder called report. However since the number of images changes vary I am unable to define this in the asset property of pkg. How do I go about this?

I've added an image of my package.json and the actual error

*Edit:
I've tried to use

```
report/*.* || report/*.png
```

but to no avail

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that these screenshots should be packed with the app?

Comment: Yes, the app basically uses the screenshot and pastes inside a docx file as part of a report.

Comment: Aren't the app making these screenshots? You only pack things that are required to run, not the ouput.

Comment: After considering what you said, I refactored my code so that it doesnt need external dynamic assets.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your question from getting closed.